# TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type (list of lists of string)

Tags: python

I have a list `r` and a list `l`

```
r = get_r()
l = [['a', 'b'], ['a'], ['c']]

print('-')
[print(type(el)) for el in l];
print('-')
[print(type(el)) for el in r];
```

will give us

```
-
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
-
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

So let's print `r` and `l`

```
print(l)
print(r)
```

will give us

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a'], ['c']]
[['Schadenersatzrecht'], ['Abgabenrecht, Finanzrecht und Steuerrecht; Verfahrensrecht'], ['Europarecht']]
```

But now as I `np.sum` those lists up:

```
np.sum(l)
np.sum(r)
```

I get:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

but also:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-0d0bce575128> in <module>()
----> 1 np.sum(r)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   1832             return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, **kwargs)
   1833     return _methods._sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 1834                          out=out, **kwargs)
   1835 
   1836 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     30 
     31 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 32     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     33 
     34 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I totally not understand what the problem is. Even printing the type in the lists of the *elements* in those lists `[print(type(el[0])) for el in r];` will give me `<class 'str'>` as a result. The types are identical - at least from what I can tell yet `np.sum` won't work on `r`.

I am not sure if one can tell what the issue is from what you can see here. The only information I can provide in addition is that `r` comes from a parsed JSON - however, I don't see why this would affect the outcome.

Comment: if you change `l` to `l = [['a'], ['a'], ['c']]` (one object per sublist) as it is for `r` you get the same behavior. What is it that you are trying to do? Why not `join()`?

Comment: You might also want to do `r = [x[0].split(";") for x in r]` to make `r` an proper list of lists (with multiple items per sublist). This will also make `np.sum` work, but as already stated, you should probably not use it at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.sum` for flattening your lists is a bad idea. Before `np.sum` is performed, both lists are coerced to np array types, which have different dtypes (although that is slightly aside the reason for failure).

```
np.array(l).dtype != np.array(r).dtype
```

You generally don't want to use `np.sum` for this.

Simply flatten your list of lists the Pythonic way using list comprehensions:

```
l = [x for lst in l for x in lst]
r = [x for lst in r for x in lst]
```